# Spring get request to Object mapping customisation ways

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, httprequest

I would LIke to know how can I map the Spring Controller GET request to my Object.

I have a situation I have both GET and POST requests enabled for a single search api.

I am receiving my POST api as JSON data type and which uses

> CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES

strategy to convert the json to my object.

Which will convert a field say date_to to dateTo in my Java modal.

But if I receive the same request over GET I need to pass dateTo instead of date_to. Which makes lots of confusion for the end user.

I was looking for something like below

```
class MySearchRequestDTO{
    private int start = 0;
    private int count = 10;

    @RequestAttribute(name="date_from")
    private Date dateFrom;

    @RequestAttribute(name="date_to")
    private Date dateTo;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Controller  Class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public ApiSuccessResponse aSearchGet(MySearchRequestDTO request) throws IMSException{
    return new ApiSuccessResponse(inventoryService.aSearch(request));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public ApiSuccessResponse aSearchPost(@RequestBody MySearchRequestDTO request) throws IMSException{
    return new ApiSuccessResponse(inventoryService.aSearch(request));
}
```

What is the best way to follow the same name strategy across my application url types in this case. Let me know if someone solved this problem the better way.

Thanks a lot for the time for reading this.

Comment: Why dont you simply change your varaiable names as you wish ?

Comment: My Models are using Camel case notations. My json is based on underscore based notation. I don't prefer to have underscore notations in my java class and its organisation wide  standard and decision to use json as underscore based. I wouldn't have posted this If I am ready to use the name like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since spring using jackson, following method works.

```
public class MySearchRequestDTO {
    int test;

    @JsonProperty("t")
    public int getTest() {
      return test;
    }

    @JsonProperty("t")
    public void setTest(int test) {
      this.test = test;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
MySearchRequestDTO c = new MySearchRequestDTO();
c.setTest(5);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println("Serialization: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(c));

MySearchRequestDTO r = mapper.readValue("{\"t\":25}",MySearchRequestDTO.class);
System.out.println("Deserialization: " + r.getTest());
```

Result:

```
Serialization: {"t":5}
Deserialization: 25
```

Comment: I dont know whether you read the question properly. I am using Jackson as serializer and I have configured to use CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES as my naming strategy. And which automatically does conversation of my field names to proper way. dateTo to date_to and while deserializing date_to to dateTo. My question the same wont happen on the GET REQUEST if I am passing the values as RequestParams. Hope you are able to understand what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

Spring use Jackson mapper for mapping json to object and vice versa. With Jackson You are able to implement own version of mapper for concrete class, so just write your own implementation of serializer and deserializer for classes you need.

Comment: Does it uses Jackson for converting REquestParams to Object ?

Comment: I am totally asking about GET request param, not about converting json object to POJO, which I am already doing successfully.